# How many certificates required to submit my app using local notification onto App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, localnotification

I am using local notification for my reminder app. Currently trying to certify my app. In the app ID in developer account, I checked the push notification option for this app, but cannot find resources explaining how to certify for local notification function.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Local notifications are not the same thing as (remote) push notifications [(which do require push notification certificates and capabilities)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1).  You only need your app store provisioning profile to submit an app incorporating local notification to the store.

[Apple has a great introductory overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/) document.  For both local and remote notifications, [users have to give your app permission](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW1).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Got it!